# How do I make an image until it is finished loading, AJAX jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make an image showing that the download process underway to complete bringing Page (2014.php) Such as wait.gif:

my example code is not working!!!! i need to make waiting image until page load... my page(2014.php) take a few minutes in this minutes i need make waiting image

```
$('#data').load('test.php');
```

example:

```
<button>Click</button>
<div id="data"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('button').click(function(){
  $('#data').html('<img src="wait.gif" />');
  jQuery.ajax({
   url: "2014.php",
   success:function(data){$('#data').html(data);}
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: your example code looks fine to me. if you're asking for how to create such an image, I suggest you ask in one a stackexchange site for image manipulation.

Comment: If you are not bothered with using a plugin then Images loaded works well -- http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: Not clear what you're asking... you want to "make" an image?  Do you mean you want to "show" an existing image (your code should be ok for this already, so can't be this)?  Somehow "create" a new image to be used here ("wait.gif") externally?  Or have jquery "generate" an image on the fly somehow?

Comment: Derek: 
my code is not working!!!!
i need to make waiting image until page load...
my page(2014.php) take a few minutes in this minutes i need make waiting image

Answer (score 1):

First, put the image on the page, and just hide it with CSS, show it when you want it to be shown and hide it when it's finished with your AJAX query:

HTML:

```
<button>Click</button>
<img src="wait.gif" class="imgWait" />
<div id="data"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgWait {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var $imgWait = $(".imgWait");  //cache your img reference in a variable

        $('button').click(function(){
            $imgWait.show(); //show the waiting image

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "2014.php",
                success:function(data){
                    $('#data').html(data);
                    $imgWait.hide(); //hide the waiting image after success
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a "loading" generator for creating your loading image, there are many online free services such as:

```
http://www.loading.io
http://www.ajaxload.info
http://preloaders.net
```

I simply googled "Ajax loaders".

Where you simply choose a design, set some other options (optional) and finally generate the gif animation for you.

Hope it helps a bit!